# Find the highest user ID in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, shell

I'm writing a script to add new users to an OS X system on the command line. I know I can list all users on a system with their user IDs using:

```
dscl . -list /Users UniqueID
```

which gives something like:

```
xxxxxxx                         937
xxxxxxxx                        939
xxxxx                           940
xxxxxx                          941
```

How can I retrieve the greatest user ID from this output to store in a variable?

Comment: For those of us who don't use OSX, can you please post a sample of what the output looks like

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will give you the line with the highest ID:

```
dscl . -list /Users UniqueID | sort -nr -k 2 | head -1
```

Comment: Ended up using: `firstid=\`dscl . -list /Users UniqueID | sort -nr -k 2 | head -1 | grep -oE '[0-9]+$'\``

Answer (score 3):

You can do this quite easily (and efficiently) with just `awk`

```
awk '$2>m{m=$2}END{print m}' file
```

To store it in a variable do:

```
highestID=$(awk '$2>m{m=$2}END{print m}' file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Combination of Scott Hunter and SiegeX's answer + some Python:

```
# Max User ID
MAXUID=`dscl . list /Users UniqueID | awk '$2>m{m=$2}END{print m}'`

# Next User ID
NEXTUID=$(( $MAXUID + 1 )) 

# Three Ways to Retrieve Specific User ID
UID=`id -u $USER`
UID=`dscl . list /Users/$USER | awk '{print $2}'`
UID=`python -c 'import pwd,os; print pwd.getpwnam(os.getenv("USER")).pw_uid'`


# Three Ways to Retrieve Max Group ID
MAXGID=`dscacheutil -q group | grep gid | awk '$2>n{n=$2}END{print n}'`
MAXGID=`dscl . list /Groups PrimaryGroupID | awk '$2>n{n=$2}END{print n}'`
MAXGID=`python -c 'import grp;print grp.getgrgid(max(g.gr_gid for g in grp.getgrall()))'`
   # notice the python method has a different max groupid
   # this is because nobody/nouser groups have negative values for PrimaryGroupID in dscl
   # but python gives these absolute values:
   # 2^32 = 4294967296
   #    if you subtract one you get 4294967295 (the max group id python returns)

# Two Ways to Retrieve Specific Group ID (i.e. staff)
STAFFGID=`dscl . read /Groups/staff PrimaryGroupID | awk '{print $2}'`
STAFFGID=`python -c 'import grp; print grp.getgrnam("staff").gr_gid'`
```